How can I REALLY ignore layers while raycasting?
So I have this code:
private Camera mainCamera;

private const int RAY_DISTANCE = 100;
private const int DEFAULT_LAYER = 0;

private void InputCheckExit()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == ONE_FINGER && Input.GetTouch(FIRST_FINGER).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        var ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, RAY_DISTANCE, ~DEFAULT_LAYER))
        {
            var clickHandler = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<UnitClickHandler>();

            if (hitInfo.transform == transform)
            {
                return;
            }
            Debug.Log($"we hit: {hitInfo.transform.gameObject.layer}");
         }
     }
}

And what I get as result? This:

HOW? I'm using only one layer! When I do Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, RAY_DISTANCE, DEFAULT_LAYER) it ignores every layer on the scene. I can't press anywhere.
Just tell me where am I stupid? I can't see any reason why raycast works like that :'(

Unity supports up to 32 layers, numbered 0 to 31.
The layer-mask you pass to a raycast is a 32 bit integer, where each bit represents one of those 32 layers and says whether or not you want to detect collisions with that layer. For example, this 32 bit binary layer mask:
00000000000000000000000000010010

would include the layers 1 and 4.
The code in the question above starts with the layer mask int DEFAULT_LAYER = 0. In binary, that looks like this:
00000000000000000000000000000000

Which means "I don't want any layers". Then the code applies the binary not operator ~ to it. This operator turns every 0 into a 1 and every 1 into a 0. So you get this layer mask:
11111111111111111111111111111111

Which means "I want every layer".

OK, so how do we build a layer mask that, let's say, only includes the layers 1 and 4?
Well, you could fiddle around with bitwise operators in C#. For example:
int layerMask = (1 << 1) | (1 << 4);

(1 << 1) This means "Put a 1 in the rightmost bit, and then move it left by one place". (1 << 4) means "Put a 1 in the rightmost bit, and then move it left by 4 places". The binary-or operator | means "give me a 1 in every bit where any of the operants has a 1". Or in other words, it combines two bitmasks.
Or you could do the math yourself and realize that the result of this is equivalent to the decimal value of 18:
int layerMask = 18;

But doing binary operations in your head can be hard when you are not used to them. Which makes the above lines of code very hard to read. So fortunately Unity offers a useful static helper method: LayerMask.GetMask. It allows you to have Unity generate a layer mask for you by providing the names of the layers you want to include:
int layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Default", "Walls");

This method is a lot more readable. But it also has two drawbacks you should be aware of: It's "stringly typed", so you won't get compile errors when you misspell a layer name. And the string comparisons make it slower than just fiddling with bits, so you should use it to build your layer masks once and then keep reusing them.

I found a discussion post by "Kurt-Dekker" that seems to cover this:

The layer is a number from 0 to 31. It corresponds to each of those named layers.
A layer MASK is a 32-bit bitfield that says which of these you want to ignore. This enables you to ignore (mask) multiple layers, each one represented by a single bit in the 32-bit integer.
In your code above, 9 (Collision) is a layer, NOT a mask. Raycast takes a layermask.
If you want to turn a layer name into a LayerMask, here’s the utility you want:
Unity LayerMask.GetMask()


I find it questionable from a copyright perspective to copy&paste an answer someone wrote on a different platform without their consent. So I wrote an answer of my own as a possible replacement.
